# BibTeX writes "pages" where it should be "page"

Tags: bibtex, page-numbering, punctuation

In a book I'm citing, the pages are numbered as following: `X-Y`, where `X` is the chapter number and `Y` is the number of the page in that chapter. For example, the fifth page of the third chapter would be numbered `3-5`.

To get the page number `3-5` in a reference, I have to write `3\-5`, since BibTeX seems to automatically replace hyphens in the page numbers with en dashes. So that's a problem I had which is solved now.

However, even after writing `pages = {3\-5}` in the BibTeX code, BibTeX writes "pages 3-5" in the bibliography, not "page 3-5". How can I make BibTeX understand that "3-5" is just one page and not a range of pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't make BibTeX see the hyphen:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{x,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={A chapter},
 booktitle={A book},
 publisher={Publisher},
 year={2012},
 pages={3\pagehyphen5},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand{\pagehyphen}{-}

\begin{document}
\cite{x}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also have the definition of the command in the `.bib` file, with a `@preamble` entry.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{"\providecommand\pagehyphen{-}"}
@inbook{x,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={A chapter},
 booktitle={A book},
 publisher={Publisher},
 year={2012},
 pages={3\pagehyphen5},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{x}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Without any extra macro, you can use `{\char45}` for the hyphen in the .bib file; however this is not the best solution, in my opinion.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{x,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={A chapter},
 booktitle={A book},
 publisher={Publisher},
 year={2012},
 pages={3{\char45}5},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{x}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can define `\pagehyphen` in the .bib file? Your code works, but if I want to give away my bibliography to someone else, I will have to provide them with the macro as well.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever -- Yes, by adding the instruction `@preamble{ "\newcommand{\pagehyphen}{--}"}` in the bib file.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Add a `@preamble` entry; I'll show it in my answer.

Comment: Great, it works! :) Thanks! Although since I need a normal hyphen, not an en dash, I added `@preamble{ "\newcommand{\pagehyphen}{-}"}` to my .bib file.

Comment: By the way, is there anyway to define `\pagehyphen` within the reference itself? If I want to give away just that reference to someone else... :P I tried that, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever You could try `\char45` instead of the hyphen.

Comment: `3{\char45}5` worked, thank you very much!